# What's the registry path for the Permanent property of the Visual Studio installer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, registry, windows-installer

I tested the permanent property of the Visual Studio installer but now I can't turn it off anymore. Although I've set Permanent back to false the installer won't remove particular files anymore. I've read that this is by design but sure there should be a registry path I can change? Or should I run a registry cleaner to get my machine back to the original state?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/90e66536-7f7e-4d12-ad1e-514ad7ea4159) MSDN forum thread for an explanation to your problem and some proposed solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I read that already before but it didn't help as the answer was a bit cryptic: "There really is no way to remove it. Somewhere on the system there's an installer component reference count for that file that will always be greater than zero." For example, I can easily edit the SharedLegacyFile property of the installer via Windows Registry but this one is not so straightforward.

Comment: Why no use file removal operations to delete the files. It is no harm that the component will remain in the system. Permanent components are supposed to do this